# converting String to date in java (complex string )

Tags: java, string, date

I am trying to convert date in String format to Date data type .

I am using `SimpleDateFormatter`.

But my date in String is in format `2012-12-24T16:45:00.000+05:30`

How can I use the simple sdf to convert?

Is this possible  in Java?

As My code is in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting ISO8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: You can't use SimpleDateFormat for ISO8601 encoded time stamps. You can read my response to the linked question for a different solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (or [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) `DateTimeFormatter`):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date date = df.parse(str);
```

The timezone part won't work with Java6. It's `XXX` in Java7, and `ZZ` in joda-time.

Comment: No, you can't parse the timezone (+05:30) with SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: You are right. I didn't know that the X format character was added in Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

You should defintely take a look at Joda-Time:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Joda time really rules, since your format is iso i believe you can use
`DateTime dt = new DateTime("2012-12-24T16:45:00.000+05:30");`
(from the top of my head, i didn't check, just remembered).

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get this String from? Xml? Then use the following method to parse the String:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar%28java.lang.String%29

Also consider using JAXB when working with XML.